# What exception does the unittest framework raise in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, assertions, python-unittest

I have a python script (main.py) that calls a method in another python script (tester.py) that performs a bunch of tests, using unittest framework, and returns. What exception does main.py look for in it's try, except block?

I've tried the following but the exception is never triggered.

```
try:
  tester.run()
except Exception, ex:
  print ex
```

According to the documentation it raises AssertionError.  However, I've tried AssertionError, Exception, but neither work.

Any ideas.

Comment: it doesnt raise an exception ... where do you see that it does?  it just returns a thing that tells you what passed and what failed ...

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

To make migrating existing test suites easier, unittest supports tests raising AssertionError to indicate test failure. However, it is recommended that you use the explicit TestCase.fail*() and TestCase.assert*() methods instead, as future versions of unittest may treat AssertionError differently.

Comment: exception AssertionError
Raised when an assert statement fails.

Comment: Line 166 of case.py in the unittest source gives the following:

    faiureException = AssertionError

Comment: thats a testcase.. you are talking about a testrunner ... which simply returns information (it caches the exception and records the data as a failure) a test runner runs a suite of tests ... it wouldnt do much good to crash out on the first error

Comment: @JoranBeasley is right - yes tests will throw `AssertionError`s when assertions in the tests fail, however these exceptions will be caught by the test runner and used to mark the result of that test as a failure. The xUnit article on Wikipedia does a decent job of explaining the roles of the different concepts (runners, suites, cases etc).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which exception is raised.

#### Method raising exception:

```
def some(self):
    try:
        msg = "My Exception"
        raise HTTPNotFound(msg)
    except Exception as e:
         raise e
```

#### Method catching exception

```
try:
    some()
except HTTPNotFound as e:
    print "Not found exception"
except Exception as e:
    print "Generic Exception"
```